# Store Array in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, local-storage

I'm currently making a Chrome Extension, and I'm at the last stage of it, storing the users preferences.
I know Local Storage will store strings, and at this stage I'm getting awway with just using strings, but as the storage requirements get bigger, a 2 dimentional array is required. I've seen that Local Storage is not capable of storaing an array, but you can use JSON. I've never used JSON, and when looking at examples, I do not understand how to do so.

```
for (i=1;i<=localStorage["totalwebsites"];i++) {
        // Get the title of the current item
        var title = localStorage["websitetitle" + i];
        // Create the new context menu item, and get its menuItemId to store in the right localStorage string
        var menuItemId = chrome.contextMenus.create({parentId: ParentID, title: title, contexts:["selection"], onclick: searchFromContext});
        // Store the created menu items menuItemId in the array so we know which item was chosen later on
        websitesarray[menuItemId] = localStorage["websiteurl" + i];
    }
```

As you can see, this gets very messy, very quick, when using strings. I was hoping for totalwebsites to become a count of the items in the array, and websitetitle and websiteurl to be in the 2 dimetional array.
I don't see how you would do this in JSON, or at least how this could be permanently stored in Chrome itself. I'm guessing you'd have to convert it back to Local Storage Strings at some point or something? I don't think I'm getting this.
Any help/pointers would be much appreciated, I can't find much :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't worry, JSON is super easy! Assuming that your websites are stored in `websitesarray`:

```
// To load:
websitesarray = JSON.parse(localstorage.websites);

// To store:
localstorage.websites = JSON.stringify(websitesarray);
```

Make sure you have a sane way to handle the case where `localstorage.websites` isn't set yet, as `JSON.parse` will throw a fit if its input is empty.

Comment: So, just to be clear, these items will be stored in the array in the order they are added? If so, that's pretty awesome. One final thing, can this be multi-dimensional, so I can store menuItemId, title and the url in the same row? So I can use `menuItemId = websitesarray[0,1];` `title = websitesarray[1,1];` and `url = websitesarray[1,2];` for the first item?

Comment: No, this is just a way to convert the array to/from a string so it can be stored in a single `localstorage` slot. JavaScript does not support multidimensional arrays directly, so you'll still need to come up with a separate solution for that. (Cleanest solution: objects. Simplest solution: separate arrays for title, URL, and ID.)

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. For now, I'll have 3 arrays (I want to see if users will want this or not), then I'll clean it up a bit by using objects. Once, again, thank you, and have a nice day.